# How to use the OpenAi functions with model gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613 with Langchain.js?

Tags: openai-api, langchain, langchain-js

I want to implement custom functions with the gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613 model, and I can't find any documentation related to this.

At this time, my codebase is something like this:

```
const model = new ChatOpenAI({
    temperature: temperature, // increase temperature to get more creative answers
    modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo-16k',
    callbacks: [
      {
        handleLLMEnd: async (output) => {
         // a callback for cost-tracing. not relevant for this question so I remove the code.

        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

Anyone can help me?

I'm triyng to implement the model gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613 on my current code-base to be able to call functions with my chatbot.